# Making an SDL Viewport with LCL

Tags: sdl, lazarus

i'm using SDL in Lazarus for creating an opengl context and also for querying the input. This works quite good but now I want to make an LCL Component which should be cross platform. Before I was using SDL_CreateWindow which creates a window for me and works without LCL.

**Edit: The problem is partly solved, see comment below!**

Now for a first test I tried to use a TForm with SDL using SDL_CreateWindowFrom. It requires some sort of window handle as a parameter. However the following source code just results in the program exiting without any error under Linux (Lazarus 1.4.0 - FPC 2.6.4 - SDL 2.0.3).

```pascal
procedure TForm1.FormClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  DC: HDC;
  H: HWND;
  WND: PSDL_Window;
begin
  SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO );
  H:= Handle;
  DC:= GetDC( Form1.Handle );
  WND:= SDL_CreateWindowFrom( Pointer( H )); //Either of these lines ...
  WND:= SDL_CreateWindowFrom( Pointer( DC )); //causes the program to just crash 
  Caption:= SDL_GetError(); // This point is never reached
end;
```

The second line where I create a window was just a test because the first was not working.
However this seems to be the normal way of doing it with Delphi under Windows:
http://ffmpeg-delphi.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/+Player/Unit1.pas

In Lazarus the TWinControl.Handle seems to be different from Delphi's TWinControl.Handle because it needs to be cross platform.
For example: http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/LCL_Interface_Redesign_Idea
But I don't understand how to get an SDL compatible handle for all platforms.

Comment: I partly solved the problem: With `PGdkPrivateWindow(PGtkWidget(Handle)^.window)^.XID` i could get the correct handle for the window (http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/LCL_Interface_Redesign_Idea). But then I cannot create an OpenGL Rendering Context because I get an error: Not an OpenGL Window. I use an old version of GLContext for now, however it does not support MacOS and the link is down (http://www.delphigl.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=10979).

Comment: I also found this: http://forums.libsdl.org/viewtopic.php?t=9578&sid=090b706304f1829218c9c0f6887cce86 They have the same issue and managed to patch sdl2 to make their window capable of opengl. However they did not seem to provide the patch or make a bug report.

Answer (score -1):

im finding this a lot w sdl,including pushing 1.13+ on people ,to drop os9 support ,which is wrong . sorry,the solution is to patch sdl,or at least the jedi headers.

the mods reference "sdl2 early days" using aa textures and gl,not used until version two . sdl is a slopheap of issues like these.

sorry i have been away from lazgfx for so long. the rv had priority ,then bandwidth to stabilize linux- low speed inet really takes a toll,running ubuntu.

I have a complete alternative to this- because I can get a gl context window in Lazarus, I'm having the backwards problem .  I believe another developer helped me solve it. "2d window" handles -via x11 accellerated rendering and trying to get lcl,sdl to handshake with them.

### I think it's five of us working on the same problem and we all need to coordinate. I'm on code Forge not GitHub.

Comment: correct. its a x11 window . you didn't set create w gl context flags. x11 doesn't presume to know what you want . therefore it didn't make a gl compatible window. x11 at first is tricky because the c,cpp is not very clear ,concise to read. check my demos. i normally do glcontext as well ,but you could write it either way. its not a hack,per se but a "window creation option ". sdl v2 presumes gl use,sdl v1 does not .